Grafana Pyroscope application CPU data
I am trying to use continuous profiling in a spring boot application using grafana pyroscope. I would like to be able to collect memory and cpu data.
The application Dockerfile looks like this:
FROM eclipse-temurin:21-jre

ENV PYROSCOPE_APPLICATION_NAME=simple.java.app
ENV PYROSCOPE_PROFILING_INTERVAL=10ms
ENV PYROSCOPE_PROFILER_EVENT=cpu
ENV PYROSCOPE_PROFILER_LOCK=10ms
ENV PYROSCOPE_PROFILER_ALLOC=512k
ENV PYROSCOPE_UPLOAD_INTERVAL=15s
ENV PYROSCOPE_LOG_LEVEL=debug
ENV PYROSCOPE_SERVER_ADDRESS=http://pyroscope:4040


ADD https://github.com/grafana/pyroscope-java/releases/download/v0.13.1/pyroscope.jar /pyroscope.jar

ADD cart-api-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar /app.jar

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8282

CMD ["java", "-XX:-Inline", "-javaagent:pyroscope.jar", "-jar", "/app.jar"]

In my docker-compose I the application container is configured as:
  app:
    build: app
    networks:
      - cart
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8082:8082"
    depends_on:
      - tempo
      - otel-collector
      - loki
      - grafana
      - prometheus
    privileged: true

In pyroscope I don't get any information related to the application cpu usage.

Which configuration am I missing?

I think your parameter needs to be changed:
ENV PYROSCOPE_FORMAT=jfr
ENV PYROSCOPE_PROFILER_EVENT=itimer

